# Request with Ajax from java script not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have this button in my HTML code :

```
<button type="submit" id="post-form" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="send()">Send</button>
```

And the java script code with function send() :

```
function send() {
           
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://app.localhost/feedback",
                dataType: "json",
                data : {
                    feedback: $('#feedback').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                },
                success : function(json) {
                    $('Backdrop').hide();
                    console.log("requested access complete");
                }
            });
        }
```

And in my views from django project I have the function related to entry-point /feedback. But the execution never arrives at the success step.
And also from postman I can send the request but from js it is not working.

The view related to my entry point is :

```
@csrf_exempt
def feedback(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        fromField = body['email']
        subject = 'New FeedBack from {}'.format(fromField)
        body = body['feedback']
        sendEmail("ex@ex.co", subject, body,
                  replyTo=['ex@ex.co', 'ex.ex@gmail.com'])

    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: One thing, you are missing a `#` or `.` in `$('Backdrop')`. try add an `error:function(e)` and see if you get something that could indicate what goes wrong.

Comment: Also this is only a guess but maybe the problem is that you return a redirect. Aka the page reloads and that might be the reason why you dont get any response.

Comment: It seems it should work. To make sure it is sending a request, check the `network` tab in your browser inspect element. If the request status is 200, then you can check for the code inside the `success` section which already has an error: you have not written a proper JQuery selector in `$('Backdrop').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Is that button a form submit button?
If so, you don't need the button's onclick event.
Try the following.

```html
<form id="yourForm">
  <button type="submit" id="post-form" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>

$("#yourForm" ).submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://app.localhost/feedback",
    dataType: "json",
    data : {
        feedback: $('#feedback').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
    },
    success : function(json) {
        $('Backdrop').hide();
        console.log("requested access complete");
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.